# Integrating Nuxt.js for SSR in a Dockerized Stack with Python FastAPI, Elasticsearch, MongoDB, and Vue.js

Tags: python, docker, vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I'm currently using a Docker Compose stack that includes:

- **Traefik** for SSL and proxying (all to the FastAPI).
- **Python FastAPI** for backend API and serving static files.
- **Elasticsearch** for search functionality.
- **MongoDB** for data storage.
- **Vue.js**, **Tailwind** **Daisy UI** for building a SPA frontend.

The routing setup (all handled by Python FastAPI) is:

- `/api/<version>/<endpoint>`: Dynamic API handled by the Python backend.
- `/api/v1/media/<id>`: Fetches images and videos from MongoDB FS using FastAPI.
- `/assets/...`: Static assets built using Vite and served by the Python backend.
- Other URLs: Default to sending index HTML, where the client fetches content by calling the API— displaying a 404 error if not found.

In the current setup, I have tried the following:

- I've experimented with managing metadata in the SPA with JavaScript, which didn't yield the desired SEO results due to crawler limitations.
- I'm exploring the integration of Nuxt.js, but am unsure how to do this efficiently in my existing stack.
- I expected that adding Nuxt.js would enhance my SEO without necessitating a major overhaul of my backend.

So, I want to integrate **Nuxt.js** for server-side rendering to improve SEO. However, I'd like to retain my existing APIs and am hesitant to shift entirely to a JavaScript-based backend due to my limited experience with JS and personal concern with its reliability and future-proof. So, I would like to know:

1. How can I integrate Nuxt.js for SSR in my existing setup in a manner that's efficient and server-friendly?
2. Would rewriting my APIs in JavaScript offer significant benefits for this integration, especially considering development and deployment aspects?
3. How can I effectively manage metadata for SEO in this JavaScript-heavy environment?

---

Additional context:

- My setup is fully containerized with Docker Compose for CI/CD.
- I'm proficient in Python but less so in JavaScript.
- Server performance and load are important considerations.
- This is small personal project in the early alpha release stage.

  - Around **700** lines of Python backend code.
  - Around **1500** lines of VUE frontend code.